# Реализовать такой hover эффект на навигации

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[image: Пример ховер эффекта]

[image: Пример ховер эффекта]

Суть вопроса: помогите реализовать такой, интересный hover эффект. При наведении на другой элемент навигации, нижняя линия должна увеличиваться в размере чтобы точка медленно передвинулась под элемент под hover. Например: Наводим на пункт Семья получаем: длина линия увеличена, позиция точки ровно в центре под пунктом Семья. Ниже приведен javascript код, пытался переделать код MagicLine плагина под себя. Но работает неправильно

```js
var $el, leftPos, newWidth, rightPos,
        $mainNav = $("#magicLineNav");
    
    $mainNav.append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");
    var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");
    
    $($magicLine)
        .width($(".nav-main").width()/2)
        .css("left", 0)
        .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
        .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());
   
    $("#magicLineNav li a").hover(function() {
        $el = $(this);
        leftPos = $el.position().left;
        newWidth = $el.parent().width();
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: leftPos
        });
    }, function() {
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
          left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
          width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
        });    
    });
```

```css
header .nav-main {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}
header .nav-main ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: 160px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
}
header .nav-main ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
header .nav-main ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
header .nav-main ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: color 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: color 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: color 0.3s ease;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
header .nav-main ul li a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -9px;
  right: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
header #magic-line {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background: #fff;
}
header #magic-line:after {
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  content: "";
  right: 0;
  top: -3px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav class="nav-main hidden-xs">
    <div class="h-name"><h1>Lorem Lorem lorem</h1></div>
    <ul class="clearfix" id="magicLineNav">
   <li class="active"><a href="index.html">О себе</a></li>
   <li><a href="family.html">СЕМЬЯ</a></li>
   <li><a href="gallery.html">Галерея</a></li> 
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function menu() {
  var menu = jQuery('#magicLineNav'),
      line = jQuery('.line'),
      start = menu.offset().left;
  jQuery('li', menu).hover(function() {
    line.width(start + $(this).position().left + $(this).width() / 2);
  }, function() {
    line.width(0);
  })
}

jQuery(function($) {
  menu();
})
```

```css
#magicLineNav {
list-style: none;
} 
.nav-main li {
float: left;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #ccc;
}
.line {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  transition: width .5s;
  margin-top: 20px;
} 
.line:after {
  content: '';
  float: right;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav class="nav-main hidden-xs">
    <div class="h-name"><h1>Lorem Lorem lorem</h1></div>
    <ul class="clearfix" id="magicLineNav">
   <li class="active"><a href="index.html">О себе</a></li>
   <li><a href="family.html">СЕМЬЯ</a></li>
   <li><a href="gallery.html">Галерея</a></li> 
    </ul>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </nav>
</header>
```